# Snowflake Stages - Can nt see

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have been loading data through ETL tool to snowflake tables, however when I executed "show stages in account " command in snowflake, it did not return any stages defined. I do not think any one of us have created external stages yet, but I was expecting to see at least the result of Snowflake managed internal stage.

Could it be my access issue ? or something else is happening ? We are connecting to snowflake through ODBC driver while loading the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have been loading data through ETL tool to snowflake tables,
>   however when I executed "show stages in account " command in
>   snowflake, it did not return any stages defined.

It's possible to load data without using a STAGE object. Snowflake supports loading files directly from an external location:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-files-directly-from-an-external-location

> I was expecting to see at least the result of Snowflake managed
>   internal stage.

If you mean "table stages", they are not separate database objects; rather, they are implicit stages tied to **the table itself**. Table stages cannot be altered or dropped. Therefore they are not listed with SHOW STAGES command.

Comment: Sorry for late response, as I was also trying to search on my end , but did not find a material where it says , snowflake can load directly without using STAGE. Can you please point me where its stated ?

Comment: I shared the direct link for it? copy into mytable
  from s3://mybucket/data/files
  credentials=(aws_key_id='$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' aws_secret_key='$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') etc...

Comment: Got it ! so ETL tools have to first create the files to Internal or external locations first and only then snowflake can consume it , it wont be possible to feed to snowflake tables directly If I understood right ,

Answer (score 0):

To load data to the internal stage, you need to define it. There is no default created stages.

There are 2 types of Stages (Internal, External) - Both are user-defined.

Internal Stages: (User, Table & Named) - User defined & **Snowflake Managed**

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-copy.html#loading-your-data

External Stages (Public Cloud-based). - User-defined & **User-Managed**

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#create-stage